# Changing whole window content with MVVM architecture

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new to WPF/MVVM and I need to create a single application window.

To clarify, I would like to have a single window with a basic menu, which, depending on the option clicked on that page/window, launches a completely new set of controllers within the same window (completely replacing the menu interface).

Basically, I'd like to be able to replace the content of the menu window, with the content of new user interface, and then to be able to go back to the menu interface again later.

Any directions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PRISM Navigation is the way to go.  You can read about [PRISM Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) on MSDN.  It provides a good explanation with a lot of code samples.  Karl Shifflett also has a couple good blog posts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/10/04/prism-v4-region-navigation-pipeline.aspx) and [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/simplifying-prism-wpf-navigation-synchronous-navigation-confirmation/) which are helpful.